# javascript variable to mvc rezor variable issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am getting keyword value which is on javascript variable but i want to replace that value to google trend script dynamically (which written inside google trend script under "keyword:" section). So i though lets convert that value to my MVC rezor view variable then replace on google trend by "@googleTrendkeyword" variable. This method not works coz i am unable to assign MVC rezor view variable with javascript variable. Whats the best solution? is it possible without MVC rezor variable convert? Whats the best practice?

Javascript:

```
<script>
 var keyword = "found some value";
</script>
```

MVC View:

```
@{ string googleTrendkeyword = 'assign the value from js variable'; }
```

Google trend script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/1173_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", { "comparisonItem": [{ "keyword": "need to set keyword value here", "geo": "", "time": "today 12-m" }], "category": 0, "property": "" }, { "exploreQuery": "q=arts&date=today 12-m", "guestPath": "https://trends.google.co.in:443/trends/embed/" });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to re-think what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Server-side code runs *on the server* before the page is even sent to the browser.  There are ways to send JavaScript values to the server (AJAX), but you can't just directly assign a variable from the future like that.

Comment: Ok. how can i achieve my goal then? i have to make google trend keyword dynamic

Comment: What do you eventually do with the `googleTrendkeyword` variable?  Why is it needed server-side at all?

Comment: Please look inside "Google trend script" the keyword should be dynamically set coz it will show google trend chart as per the keyword. make sense? @David

Comment: Then it's not clear to me why you need to involve server-side code at all.  Why can't you use the JavaScript variable `keyword` there?

Comment: coz it is inside trends.embed.renderExploreWidget(with some object inside) ..how can i make keyword dynamic i dont care its by js or c#. i just need to achieve it

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  That call to `trends.embed.renderExploreWidget` is in JavaScript.  So just use your JavaScript variable there.  There's no need to involve server-side code at all here.

Comment: If you want to use a js variable value in C# code, you need to send it from client to server (where c# gets executed). one way is ajax. But without know what your specific use case is, it is hard to suggest the exact solution which will work for you.

Comment: Ok. Please give me idea to set keyword value inside trends.embed.renderExploreWidget() using javascript

Comment: @JohnLk: Just use your variable.  `... "keyword": keyword, ...`  As long as you set the value of the variable before you use it, and as long as it's in scope, then that's exactly what variables are used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "pass" a Razor variable to a JavaScript variable but not the other way around.
It would be possible by placing the variable in @HTML.Hidden field like

```
@Html.Hidden("variableName", VariableValue);
```

for JavaScript:

```
<script>
     console.log("Variable value: ", variableName.value);// OR WHATEVER FUNCTION YOU WANT TO PERFORM
</script>
```